# Reading from PSV file Java

Tags: java

I want to read a PSV file using java. Records in my PSV file has 4 columns. I want to read and output only the 3 and 4th column. What is the best way to do this.
Here is what I have:

```
BufferedReader PSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String dataRow = PSVFile.readLine();
while (dataRow != null)
{
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\n");
    for (String item:dataArray) 
    {
        String[] elements = item.split("|");
        System.out.println(item);
    }
    System.out.println();
    dataRow = PSVFile.readLine();
}
PSVFile.close();
System.out.println();
```

Based on @AljoshaBre suggestion Iam using CSVReader, doing this:

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName),'|');
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) 
{
 System.out.println( nextLine[3] + nextLine[4]);
}
```

I am getting the desired output but then get an error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at Read_PSV.main(Read_PSV.java:20)
Line 20 is System.out.println( nextLine[3] + nextLine[4]);

Comment: Pipe separated, or period separated?

Comment: If you're getting that exception, it probably means that your array of tokens isn't as big as you think it is.  Perhaps you're not properly dealing with blank lines (ie. 0 or 1 length token arrays (depending on what opencsv wants to give you back in that case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is my weapon of choice.

This snippet will get you third and forth columns:

```
try {
    //last parameter tells it which line (row) to consider as the first one
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("res/test.csv"), '|', '\0', 1);
    String[] row;

    List<String> columnThree    = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> columnFour     = new ArrayList<String>();

    while((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        columnThree.add(row[2]);
        columnFour.add(row[3]);
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It will print

```
Nikola
Nenad
Ljubinka
Gordana
```

for this input:

***test.psv***

```
Name|Surname|Father|Mother
Aleksandar|Milic|Nikola|Ljubinka
Nebojsa|Jakovljevic|Nenad|Gordana
```

Comment: I am using CSVReader now but get an error. See original post for details.

Comment: Your loop isn't good. Try to get the columns using CSVReader get() method, like I did.

Comment: @AljoshaBre- There does not seem to be a get() method.I get the following error. "The method get(int) is undefined for the type CSVReader"

Answer (score 0):

Commons-Lang has a nice class for this as well:

```
// get a csv instance (which is cloned, so we can customize it)
StrTokenizer tokenizer = StrTokenizer.getCSVInstance();

// Set delimiter char
tokenizer.setDelimiterChar('|');

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.psv"));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  // set the input on the tokenizer
  tokenizer.reset(scanner.nextLine());
  // get the tokens
  String toks[] = tokenizer.getTokenArray();
}
```

NOTE:  StrTokenizer itself is designed to work on a single record at a time, so you have to use something like java's Scanner to pull in a line at a time.  The StrTokenizer itself is re-usable (though not threadsafe) via the "reset" method.

It has a host of options such as quote characters, whitespace handling, empty token handling, etc...  Not sure offhand what options opencsv would have.